# Corda Transaction is stalled when contacting notary service

Tags: corda

I am using Corda Version 1. Transaction is not getting completed when I am running nodes on docker environment. It got stuck after this logs:

```
Flow logs >> Generating transaction based on new Trade Details.
Flow logs >> Verifying contract constraints.
Flow logs >> Signing transaction with our private key.
Flow logs >> Gathering the counterparty's signature.
Flow logs >> Structural step change in child of Gathering the counterparty's signature.
Flow logs >> Collecting signatures from counter-parties.
Flow logs >> Verifying collected signatures.
Flow logs >> Done
Flow logs >> Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.
Flow logs >> Structural step change in child of Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.
Flow logs >> Requesting signature by notary service
Flow logs >> Structural step change in child of Requesting signature by notary service
Flow logs >> Requesting signature by Notary service
```

I can see this message in the controller logs:

```
[INFO ] 2017-10-27T07:27:57,024Z [Messaging] messaging.NodeMessagingClient.createQueueIfAbsent - Create fresh queue internal.peers.8Kqd4oWdx4KQGHGNkbLbDP3bxDkm43Gy7NpJqGdiL5G2PwRdVu9dngMkJkp bound on same address
[WARN ] 2017-10-27T07:29:57,111Z [Messaging] messaging.NodeMessagingClient.sendWithRetry - Reached the maximum number of retries (3) for message ClientMessageImpl[messageID=0, durable=true, address=internal.peers.8Kqd4oWdx4KQGHGNkbLbDP3bxDkm43Gy7NpJqGdiL5G2PwRdVu9dngMkJkp,userID=null,properties=TypedProperties[platform-version=1,corda-vendor=Corda Open Source,release-version=1.0.0,platform-topic=platform.session,session-id=0,_AMQ_DUPL_ID=0efb502e-15f6-4b0a-bdf9-8296571f228f]] redelivery to internal.peers.8Kqd4oWdx4KQGHGNkbLbDP3bxDkm43Gy7NpJqGdiL5G2PwRdVu9dngMkJkp
```

Comment: Looks like your node cannot communicate with the notary. Are you sure that the notary is available?

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? The controller has received a message from the node, but can't communicate back. But that would be weird, as I assume the controller is the network map as well as the notary in this set-up. If it's having trouble communicating with the nodes, how did they register with the network map in the first place?

Comment: Controller has received a message from the node but can't communicate back, yes it has registered on first place and if i do rest call for /peers then i am getting other nodes as well.

Comment: The fact that you can do a rest call for /peers does not mean that the controller is able to send outbound messages to other nodes. This is because to get a list of peers, the controller queries the network map, which is himself!

Comment: Please share node configurations. My guess is p2pAddress which cannot be reached by  other nodes.

Comment: I have solved this problem by using actual host machine IP address in p2pAddress while creating node container. it was mapped as localhost in p2pAddress, however i have already exposed container ip with hostmachine ip. so ideally this should not be the issue. however it's creating issues if we are using localhost.    many thanks for support.

Comment: @ChintanKansara - feel free to answer your own question then - this will help others find the solution if they also have the same problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using actual host machine IP address in p2pAddress while creating node container.

It was mapped as localhost in p2pAddress and i have already exposed container ip with hostmachine ip. therefore ideally this should not be the issue, however it's creating issue while signing notary service if we are using localhost. many thanks for support.